# No changes seen after pushing to Git. Git Internal Server Error

Tags: git, github

> **Moderator Note**: This error happens when GitHub has an outage or service degradation. We're leaving it up as a canonical post for others to see and close against as duplicates, but [questions about service outages are off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326329).

There are similar questions but I could not find any answer that would solve the issue.

```
git status

On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I retract the local changes to the original state of last commit:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Make sure it is up to date:

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then make a small modification in the file.

```
git status

On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   test.py

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

And so as always I do:

```
git add test.py
git commit -m "updating test.py"
git push -u origin master
```

which gives:

```
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 281 bytes | 281.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
remote: Internal Server Error
Everything up-to-date
```

However, the changes are not seen on the github page. Now, `git status` gives:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: The *internal server error* message coming from the remote (hence prefixed by `remote:`) means that something has gone wrong on the other (GitHub) end. They did not say anything further, but it looks as though the error resulted in the push being rejected. You could try again, but if it keeps happening, the only possible next step is to contact some human being at the other (GitHub) end and have them investigate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue continued for 2 days and then without changing anything, the 'git push' went through.

Answer (score 19):

The `(internal server error)` message is typically representative of a Github outage. The status of GitHub can be observed at https://www.githubstatus.com/